# How to represent a method call that's through inheritance in a sequence diagram? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, uml, sequence-diagram

```
class FirstClass < SecondClass; end

class SecondClass
  include ThirdModule 
end

module ThirdModule
  def inherited_method 
  end
end
```

How would I represent `FirstClass.new.inherited_method` in a UML sequence diagram? I want to explicitly show that the method is inherited from the ThirdClass (because I'm going to draw a parallel to another sequence that is also using the same inherited method).

Comment: One cannot `include` classes in Ruby, only modules.

Comment: good catch - edited to be a module

Comment: You can model FirstClass, SecondClass and ThirdModule as separate lifelines and show the message flow from the public interface to the inherited implementation as messages between the lifelines. The `new` message would be shown as the UML create message (https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#create)

Comment: Thank you this is how I planned to approach it but wasn't sure if it would be correct or not

Comment: @xmojmr That would be wrong in this case. There is only one instance, namely the one that inherits. (Just assuming that "<" denotes inheritance)

Comment: @ThomasKilian SecondClass would be UML classifier and the messages it would accept would be its static methods. Some sort of virtual method table which in C++ exists in one instance for each class and each of it's methods receives the object instance - the `this` pointer

Comment: @xmojmr I don't know how the c++ compiler is constructed, but I made my diploma with compiler construction. So from that background I'd say that just one instance is created and the `this` keyword will just instruct to use the non-overridden code and not to dispatch to another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though my Ruby is a bit rusted, here's an approach. A class diagram would look like

[image]

(assuming that the "<" operator in Ruby is inheritance). `ThirdModule` is stereotyped with `<<module>>` since it's just a container for some operations and not a real class. This is no standard but something you need to introduce in the domain where you are modeling.

A call to `inherited_method` would look like

[image]

Note that tools like Enterprise Architect can not recognize the imported operations and will not offer them in the message list to `FirstClass` so you need to type it manually.